# Priority of universal selector in CSS

Tags: css, selector, universal

I'm learning CSS and have a question regarding the * selector. I understood  that it applies its styles on every single element within the document.

However, when I define a different style (background-color) for body and still another for paragraph, the style within the * selector is only applied to the body and not to the paragraph. See https://jsfiddle.net/oz8a1rn4/1/

```css
* {
  background-color: grey;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero soluta enim aut! Nihil nam obcaecati, fugiat sint sit libero voluptate eos incidunt odio neque cum, dignissimos aperiam, magnam nisi debitis.</p>
```

Comment: That is due to `Cascading-Style-Sheet`. Short `CSS`. In your case following rules overwrite earlier ones. Also `Inline-CSS` is higher in the `cascade` than that in your `stylesheet`.

Comment: [Here with `body` in blue.](https://jsfiddle.net/oz8a1rn4/2/)

Comment: Thats true. The * selector selects all elements.

The * selector can also select all elements inside another element.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually what I'm trying to understand is why the * selector overwrites the style of my body, but not the one of my paragraph.

Comment: The body is blue, it's just that your paragraph is taking up the entire body so you don't see it. Don't believe me? Try adding a div after your paragraph, or set the paragraph's opacity to zero.

Comment: Oh yeah I believe you! You see it indeed when adding a div. Didn't think of that filling up aspect. So if I'm not mistaking, the style Of the * selector is the very first style which is applied, right? And after that the other styles are applied, taking into account origin, merge, inheritence and specificity?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, correct me if I am wrong, this is happening due to the effects of the css cascade.
See [intro to the css cascade.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance)

The * (universal) selector has no effect on css specificity.
The body and p have the same value of specificity (value 1).
Therefore, the next step in the cascade to decide which styles are chosen is *source order*. Later rules will win over the earlier rules, therefore, the background styling will be red.

Comment: Thank you gary, but I don't think that source order, nor specificity are in the game here. I've already tried to swich the sequence of the 3 style definitions, but with the same result. I'm thinking now that the sequence of the style applications is as follows: 1.The * selector puts it to grey on every element, so the body and the paragraph.  2. The paragraph inherits the grey color from the body.   3. The inherited grey color of the paragraph is overwritten by the paragraph style definition and becomes red. So first the * selector does its job and afterwards inheritence and overwriting happen

Comment: And that is also why AJAX his suggestion, adding the html tag in the style definition of the body, like in https://jsfiddle.net/oz8a1rn4/2/ puts the background of the body in blue.Then 1. The * puts every element grey.   2. Body inherits grey from html.  3. body becomes blue because of its style definition.  4. paragraph inherits blue from body   5. paragraph becomes red because of its style definition.  Think I got it!

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that the style `background-color:grey` is applied for the `HTML` element like this:

```css
html {
  background-color: grey;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero soluta enim aut! Nihil nam obcaecati, fugiat sint sit libero voluptate eos incidunt odio neque cum, dignissimos aperiam, magnam nisi debitis.</p>
```

This overlaps the blue style of the body which can be explained with the following snippet:

```css
* {
  background-color: grey;
}

html {
 background-color: initial;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero soluta enim aut! Nihil nam obcaecati, fugiat sint sit libero voluptate eos incidunt odio neque cum, dignissimos aperiam, magnam nisi debitis.</p>
```

In the second snippet we reset the color change of the `html` element to `initial` value. This then shows the blue background color of `body` and thus is evidence that blue color of the body is just masked by the `html` element.

Here is also a screenshot (chrome devtools using **your** example) that proofs that the blue color was applied to the  `body` element, but just masked by the `html` element:

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer Willem. But without the initial value the body is also blue while the html is grey (value in the * selector style), so my assumption is that first the style in the * selector is applied to every element and after that, the other styles are applied.